# Nested lists with indenting dynamic paddings

Tags: javascript, css, nested, html-lists

Take a look at my code example at js bin:
http://jsbin.com/iritep/3/edit

I'd like to indent the yellow colored  item without continuing my hard coded css-rule:

```
ul li a {padding-left: 20px;}
ul li ul li a {padding-left: 40px;}
ul li ul li ul li a {padding-left: 60px;}
ul li ul li ul li ul li a {padding-left: 80px;}   /* don't want this line! */
```

Can I possibly make this css more dynamic without having to add the last line of css?

Comment: Is it important that the space to the left of each link counts as part of the link?

Comment: you can at least omit all but the first the `ul` in your selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, Stackoverflow didn't allow me to comment twice in such short notice. Here is the link to the solution to my problem.

http://jsbin.com/iritep/5/edit#javascript,html,live

Answer (score 0):

Change your css-rules slightly, you could do the following:

```
ul li{
  padding-left:20px;
}
```

This would indent every new level 20px further. See, if that still suits you. (indenting lists generally brings some minor styling-restrictions (like coloring a single line via `li` or `a` Element.))

Comment: Yes,but the problem is that I need the borders to stretch out to the edges of the screen. I solved it like this:

Comment: This still does not perform what he is looking for; he is looking to make different paddings based on the level the list is in.

Comment: @WilliamCallahan Well, it does exactly this nesting structure: http://jsbin.com/mumayirufa/1/edit The only thing it does not (because CSS cannot do this) is maintain the length of the list items (which however was not included in the initial question).